# How to define a PixelShuffle Layer?

Tags: image-processing, neural-networks

PixelShuffleLayer come from [Real-Time_Single_Image](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/Shi_Real-Time_Single_Image_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf).

[image]

Firstly, a $C\times H\times W$ image, after a convolution, now $f^2\cdot C \times H\times W$, then sub-pix, finally get a $ C \times fH\times fW$ image.

Let me take a $3\times 4\times 3$ image with $f=2$ as an example:

```
SeedRandom[42]
afterConv=RandomReal[1,{2^2*3,4,3}];
ArrayFlatten[Transpose[ArrayReshape[#,{2,2,4,3}],{3,4,1,2}],2]&/@Partition[afterConv,4]
```

If we do a step decomposition:

```
MatrixForm/@(m1a=First@Partition[afterConv,4])
MatrixForm[m1b=ArrayReshape[m1a,{2,2,4,3}]]
MatrixForm[m1c=Transpose[m1b,{3,4,1,2}]]
MatrixForm[m1d=ArrayFlatten[m1c,2]]
```

[image]

But `NetChain` can't receive the functions above, it can only use Layers.

So how do I define a `PixelShuffleLayer[f_Integer]`?

---

### Update-20180920:

Notice that that the color channel, the width and height of the picture are variable.

I tried to decompile the MXNet diagram definition to find how MXNet can do this.

```
{
    MXNetLink`Symbol`PackagePrivate`mxSymbolCreator["Reshape", {"shape" -> "(0, -4, -1, 4, 0, 0)"}],
    MXNetLink`Symbol`PackagePrivate`mxSymbolCreator["Reshape", {"shape" -> "(0, 0, -4, 2, 2, 0, 0)"}],
    MXNetLink`Symbol`PackagePrivate`mxSymbolCreator["transpose", {"axes" -> "(0, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3)"}],
    MXNetLink`Symbol`PackagePrivate`mxSymbolCreator["Reshape", {"shape" -> "(0, 0, -3, -3)"}]
}
```

While `ReshapeLayer` only accept a list of positive integers.

So try `` NeuralNetworks`MXLayer `` or `` NeuralNetworks`DefineLayer ``.

Comment: A big problem is that `ReshapeLayer` doesn't seem to support `Automatic`, but it works in MXNet. See [PixelShuffle in MXNet](https://discuss.gluon.ai/t/topic/5509/3)

Comment: ["Shape polymorphism"](https://discuss.mxnet.io/t/proposal-new-merge-dims-reshaping-op/1524/5) will be in Mathematica 12. Additional [link 1](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/pull/11928) and [link 2](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/pull/12064)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
net = NetChain[
  {
   FlattenLayer[-1],
   TransposeLayer[],
   ReshapeLayer[{7, 7, 3, 3}],
   TransposeLayer[2 <-> 3],
   ReshapeLayer[{21, 21}]
   },
  "Input" -> {9, 7, 7}
  ]
```

[image]

```
colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Orange, Pink, Purple};

Table[Grid[ConstantArray[i, {7, 7}], Frame -> All, Background -> colors[[i]]], {i, 9}]
```

[image]

```
net@Table[ConstantArray[i, {7, 7}], {i, 9}] // 
 ArrayPlot[#, ColorRules -> Thread[N@Range[9] -> colors], Mesh -> All] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I have already figure out how `NeuralNetworks` runs, this should work:

```
Input: ChannelT[$$InputChannels, TensorT[$$InputSize]]

Output: ChannelT[$$OutputChannels, TensorT[$$OutputSize]]

Parameters:
    $Scaled: PosIntegerT
$$InputChannels: SizeT
$$InputSize: SizeListT[2]
$$OutputChannels: ComputedType[SizeT, $$InputChannels / $Scaled^2]
    $$OutputSize: ComputedType[SizeListT[2], $$InputSize * $Scaled]

Writer: Function[
    input = GetInput["Input", "Batchwise"];
    index = SowNode["reshape", input, "shape" -> {0, -4, -1, #Scaled^2, 0, 0}];
    index = SowNode["reshape", index, "shape" -> {0, 0, -4, #Scaled, #Scaled, 0, 0}];
    index = SowNode["transpose", index, "axes" -> {0, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3}];
    index = SowNode["reshape", index, "shape" -> {0, 0, -3, -3}];
    SetOutput["Output", index]
]
```

It's not the standard Wolfram Language, it's a kind of DSL(domain-specific language),using special way to import.

Save this as a `*.m`, then load with:

```
<< NeuralNetworks`
System`PixelShuffleLayer
file = "the saved file.m";
def = AssociateTo[NeuralNetworks`Private`ReadDefinitionFile[file, "System`"], "Suffix" -> "Layer"]
NeuralNetworks`DefineLayer["PixelShuffle", def];
```

The test result is the same as @Alexey Golyshev's

```
net = NetChain[{PixelShuffleLayer[3], FlattenLayer[1]}, "Input" -> {9, 7, 7}]
colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Orange, Pink, Purple};
draw = ArrayPlot[#, ColorRules -> Thread[N@Range[9] -> colors], Mesh -> All]&;
net@Table[ConstantArray[i, {7, 7}], {i, 9}] // draw
```

[image]

The new function `PixelShuffleLayer` is exactly the same as built-in layers.

It can adapt the shape of the input, just try `NetReplacePart[net,"Input"->{27,64,36}]`.

The only problem is that models with custom layers cannot be imported back.

Unless the exact same `NeuralNetworks` module is used.

I hope Mathematica 12 can have a better support on the custom layers.